# Melhor opção para substituir IFRAMES

Tags: html, html5, aplicação-web, iframe

Atualmente estou trabalhando no desenvolvimento de uma plataforma com muitas funcionalidades e paginas diferentes, estamos usando IFRAMES para poupar repetidos carregamentos (Menu, atalhos, etc), entretanto o uso de IFRAMES para sistemas não é uma boa pratica, como e pelo que posso substituir as IFRAMES, mantendo a ideia de evitar muitos carregamentos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá amigo tudo bem? Considere usar DIV ao invés de IFRAME. Mas para que as atualizações de elementos HTML dentro de uma DIV será necessário utilizar Javascript e/ou algum framework JS como AngularJS ou mesmo e bom e velho JQuery. Ambos usando HttpXmlRequest (AJAX) para autalização assincrona e dinâmica. Sucesso!!!

Comment: A questão é que estou executando trechos server-side dentro das paginas que são carregadas no iframe, não sei qual seria o comportamento da requisição nesse ambiente.